# Rust Graphics Library

Tags: image, graphics, jpeg, rust

I want to make simple program that can accept jpg images and make optimal arrangement on a given format (A4, A3, A2 paper etc...) and output new image that contains optimally arranged images on an A4/A3/... format.

I saw that there are some libraries but are more suited for game development. I just need something that can read data from jpeg (width, height, resolution, color profile etc...) and can perform some basic operations on image.

Comment: This was posted on reddit/r/rust today:
https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/rust-image

Comment: @abject_error seems good. Any chance you can put this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/rust-image, which was released quite recently.

The other way is to use https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen to create bindings for your favourite C image manipulation library.